# PERMANOVA and random/fixed effects

Tags: mixed-model, model, fixed-effects-model, permutation-test

I'm really lost in this topic, and I want to ask for help here.
I have a continous variable of interest (X), but also factors that I think they can affect my results (for me the most interesting factor is Sampling site). So, I have made this formula for adonis2:
X ~ Sampling Site + Year + Sex + Age + Sample Type
(Sampling site has 2 levels, Year has 4 categories, Sex has 2, Age has 2, Sample type has 2)

-Are these factors fixed in this way?
-Is this formula right? I know that changing order makes results to be different. Maybe because not all factors have exactly the same n by category? My total n is also <30

Any help/advice/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!
Thank you in advance!